# Problem with insert data into Derby database

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc, derby

Problem with insert data into Derby database

I use jsp and servlet, but I have try so many time but still can not insert data into database, it only shows
List of students with score:

and nothing else, it should insert user input into database, database connection is set, id data type is number , marks is int, name is varchar. 
No error in program I also add javaDB Driver to Libraries, I just do not understand what is  wrong.

index.jsp

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>Student Score</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Welcome to Student Score Application</h1>

            <form method="post" action="Result.jsp">
                <input type="submit" value="View Data">
            </form>

            <br>
            <form method="post" action="servletAdd">
                ID:<input type="text" name="ID"><br>
                Name:<input type="text" name="name"><br>
                Marks:<input type="text" name="marks"><br>

                <input type="submit" value="Add">
                <input type="reset" value="Clear">
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Result.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Result</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>List of students with score:</h1>

        <%@page import="java.sql.*"%>

        <%
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");

         Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/abc","abc","abc");

         Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

         String sql = "SELECT * FROM ABC";

         ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

         while(rs.next()){

             String id = rs.getString("id");
             String name = rs.getString("name");
             int marks = rs.getInt("marks");

         out.println("ID: "+ id);
         out.println("Name: "+name);
         out.println("Marks: "+marks);
         %><br>
     <%
         }
         //STEP 6:
         rs.close();
         stmt.close();
         con.close();
            %>  
    </body>
</html>
```

servletAdd.java

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

public class servletAdd extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String JDBC_DRIVER = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver";
        String DB_URL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/abc";

        String USER ="abc";
        String PASS ="abc";
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;

        String id = request.getParameter("ID");
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        int marks = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("marks"));

        try{

            Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/abc",USER,PASS);

            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String sql = "INSERT into ABC values"+"("+ "'"+ id +"'"+ ","+ name + ","+ "'"+ marks+"'"+")";

            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

            stmt.close();
            conn.close();


        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+"/Result.jsp");    
    }
}
```

Comment: For the first aid in such cases: `System.out.println("Insert-Statement: " + sql);` After that copy this printed query and execute it into you databàse tool.

Comment: Please.  Throw out whatever book or tutorial that has you adding scriptlet code to a JSP.  This has been the wrong way to do it since 1999.  Please stop.

Comment: @reporter thanks， i try to use insert statement in database but error ,so i rewrite the insert statement and now it work.